# Chrome remote desktop does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, android, remote-desktop

I just recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and my chrome remote desktop doesn't work. I am working only with the "My Computer" section. I've set up my home computer and I am trying to access it through CRD on Android but I get the following error:

```
The remote computer is not responding to connection requests. Please verify that it is online and try again.
```

Even though my home computer is shown as online on the list in CDR.

I've been looking for solutions on Google but nothing worked.

UPDATE: I have two routers at home one which is the main which is actually connected to the internet and another which connects to the first router. So maybe Chrome Remote Desktop doesn't work because my desktop computer is connected to the second router?

Comment: Did you ever get it working? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no : ( decided not to spent time on it.